# ''node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' in vscode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, netsuite, vscode-extensions

I'm working on setting up the Suitecloud Development Framework in the NetSuite instance for my company. I've installed Node v16.13.0, npm 8.1.0, and suitecloud 1.3.1.

Running node -v, npm -v, etc. all works from cmd but will throw a not recognized error when I use the terminal in VSCode.

I can get my VSCode to identify node with

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

but this only fixes it for the session and still doesn't give me access to run anything from suitecloud.

I've checked my Environment Variables as per every other help section I've found for this issue but I have 'C:\Program Files\nodejs' in both my user PATH variable any my system PATH variable.

I've tried running VSCode as Admin on the off chance that would fix it, but that didn't solve anything either.

Thank you for your time, hopefully I'm overlooking something simple due to my inexperience with the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving VSCode overnight and then rebooting seems to have fixed it. I can't explain why, but if you're encountering the same issue I recommend walking away and coming back to it after a long delay.

Comment: I didn't have to leave it overnight, but I had to close all instances of VSCode to get the terminal to reload the new node installation. I had 4 VSCode windows open, closing all of them, then reopening got it sorted